# Can I configure Thunderbird to update "sent" in the background?

Tags: thunderbird, imap

In my copy of Thunderbird (for Mac), the Sent folder for my IMAP account does not refresh its contents automatically. It only refreshes its contents when I actually go up and click into the Sent folder -- which of course therefore means that I have to wait 4-10 seconds for the folder to actually refresh to display the newest contents.  This results in sluggish Sent-folder performance.

How can I tell Thunderbird that I want it to refresh the contents of Sent (or any other IMAP folder) in the background, every XX number of minutes, so that when I click over into Sent, it is more likely to have the most recent items in it?

Comment: I have the same issue. Thunderbird 31.5.0 on Win 7 SP1.